# Sending a text to google chrome address bar

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to send a url to the google chrome address bar. I open a process of google chrome with `CreateProcess()` winapi. Then i find the window with the

```
Hwnd hwnd = FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", "New Tab - Google Chrome");
```

I wanted to send the text of the url via Window Messages but it can't make it to work.

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CHAR, 'A',1);
```

Perhaps , someone could point me to the right direction. Maybe there is another way to send the characters to the google address bar.

Comment: `SetWindowText()` maybe?

Comment: i want to send the text of the url to the address bar of google chrome not to the title of the window

Comment: @TheBrowser You probably need to get the handle of the address bar control.

Comment: The thing , that it is not the same as in IE, where you have the hwnd of the address bar control. I use spy++ and i don't see hwnd of the address control. Perhaps in google they use something different

Comment: Since Chrome doesn't implement its address bar through a native window, this won't work (besides being from for many other reasons). However, [chrome.automation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/automation) is on its way. Until then, use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: For all we know it is compeletely native, just a windowless control.  But the odds are good that it is something from some widget toolkit that Google likes to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to open up chrome with an address, just `CreateProcess` for chrome.exe and pass url as the command line argument.

If you want to mess with existing chrome tab, it is against user expectation and probably introduce security risk.

Comment: I wanted to mess with the second option. Did not intend to do anything risky just to be able to open a website by sending key strokes.

Comment: Chrome itself does not provide "reuse tab" option, you need to write browser plugin, or use apple-script on mac. Anything else (e.g. replay macro: ctrl-L, address, enter) is a hack.

Comment: What security risk do you have in mind? I cannot see one.

Comment: Direct reading the current url address of user is obviously against user privacy and may expose user session key in some scenario. Writing/Changing the user's current page without user awareness may present fake page to user, imagine you checking gmail and your chrome suddenly change to a fake login page telling you session expired and ask for password, user may not aware the address has changed.

Comment: How is any of this a security risk? An application that performs those actions can only do so, if it is running in a security context, granting sufficient privileges.

Comment: My opinion of "changing user's current browser tab without user awareness" is a security risk, it's irrelevant if the background app has admin right or not, the user just won't expect that. If you want to dig deeper I think it worth a new question, since while I bring it out it seems not the major concern of OP.

Comment: You completely misunderstand security. The fact that an application can change things around in another application is not a security risk. This application has been explicitly given permission to do so, by an authorized entity. Changing a user's content in the browser's address bar does not **introduce** a security risk. Installing the software may have.

Comment: This is a process hijack, plain and simple.  If the operation was legitimate processes would expose an API or IPC mechanism.  Windows spelunking is not a normal practice and should always be viewed with high suspicion.